# object required error for if statement visual basic

Tags: vba

I want to set up a code in VBA to identify any cells in a range which are not numberic (e.g #NUM!) and replace it with a statement. For all cells which contain a number I want to keep the value of this number
My code is

```
Sub convert_cell()
    Dim c As range
    For Each c In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cells
       If c Is Number Then
           c.Value = c.Value
       Else: c = "no ROI"
       End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

However I get the message : Run time error "424" . Object required.

Comment: Is c an object? (jong time ago I used vba)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Yes, c is defined as range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub convert_cell()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
       If IsNumeric(c) Then
           c.Value = c.Value
       Else: c = "no ROI"
       End If
    Next c
End Sub
```